# Is it possible to change some content of a view without completely re-render it in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently making a calendar where users can click on dates, and a popup window then shows the events of the date that user clicked at. However, we don't know which date the user will be clicked at before rendering, the content of the window cannot be determined. Is there any way I can dynamically change the content of an element after a user action ("click" or "hover") in Express.js?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, make a separate API route that returns JSON and fetch it using client side JS and integrate it into the page without a reload.

This is a very common pattern in React.

Also this method is called AJAX, so you might look that up too!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can dynamically change the content of an element after a user action ("click" or "hover")

That would be the responsibility of client-side javascript. It seems like you need a  in the html file your express code is serving.

Comment: Yes, I have the html and client-side js ready, but how do I pass the data from server-side (node.js) to client-side when using DOM to detect a click or hover

Comment: In that case, see trognanders answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74754208/7869269

Comment: @AnsonNg you are thinking of it backwards, express doesn't choose to send the data, but your client side asks for it in the event handler (using fetch or something). How you put that in html depends, in react you would write it to state, but for a homebrew thing you would call some kind of render function.